# ubuntu xl2tp ppp0 not properly handling the DF flag (Packet Corrupt) while sending packages > defined MTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pptp, vpn, xl2tpd

While trying to setup an Ubuntu Linux server as a client to an l2tp/IPSEC server, I notice inconsistencies while trying to send data.

The tunnel/VPN establish the connection / handshake properly and from the client I can ping / ssh to all the machines as expected.

I notice the problem while trying to send data from the client to a remote machine while using scp.

I can copy / get anything without problems:

```
scp user@vpn:/tmp/test.file
```

But if I try to send data and the file size to be sent is > the vpn [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) (1280):

```
scp /tmp/test.file user@vpn:/tmp
```

I get a "**Packet Corrupt**" message.

Without success I tried this: `ethtool -K eth0 tx off`

Using tcpdump I notice that all outgoing packages no matter the size all contain the DF flag, for some reason packages going through the ppp0 interface where not fragmented.

The configuration I am using is:

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-mschap-v2
noccp
noauth
idle 1800
mtu 1280
mru 1280
defaultroute
usepeerdns
debug
lock
connect-delay 5000
```

Some of the logs I get:

```
pppd[26423]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0x4501dc87]
pppd[26423]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x1 magic=0xd6736575]
```

If I send files in chunks bigger than the MTU:

```
pppd[12603]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xb8af
pppd[12603]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x8 ...]
```

A way around to this is to use rsync and limit the outgoing bandwidth:

```
rsync -vvv --bwlimit=16 -P -e "ssh -i ssh_key.pem" /tmp.test.file user@vpn:/tmp
```

Other clients running iOS / OS X from same network have no issues at all, both can send/get data with out any problems, therefore I am not suspecting a problem with the VPN server.

Any ideas or possible patches to fix this issue?